# Error with HTML/iframe in FireFox - Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHistory.pushState]

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, document.write

I am creating a small javascript simulation of a java-based (JSF) server. The bootstrap javascript file will download and parse a bunch of files using AJAX, and then generate a large HTML string. This HTML string is a full HTML document - it has a doctype, head, script includes, inline scripts, body, etc.

The reason I do not want to use the real JSF back-end is because I would like to be able to have a pure UI environment to test my code without any java/oracle server slowing me down.

I want to share my code (in a .zip file for example) with anyone and they should be able to open the page (with a small loading screen while the AJAX calls are made) in any browser without some server already installed on their machine.

The answer to that question led me to explore more - now I've run into a different error but I cannot seem to explain it.

[Fiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/EnFRv/) : This one attempts to put the HTML into an iframe using the iframe's document.write. In this HTML there is a script that pushes a new history state `history.pushState(null, null, hash)`

[Fiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/EnFRv/1/) : This one attempts to put the HTML into the iframe, but this time it just uses `location.hash = hash`

Both fiddles seem to work fine in Chrome and Safari and IE 9 - but Firefox gives the following error:

`NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHistory.pushState]`

I don't understand this error - if you do this same code `history.pushState(null,null,"#test")` on any page in firefox using the javascript console in FireBug it works fine - but in this particular situation it doesn't work.

I also tried to perform `document.open(); document.write(html); document.close()` on the document in the current page (instead of creating an iframe), but the same problem happened - only this time if I put break points in firebug into javascript code inserted in the HTML fragment, the breakpoints don't work which would mean I could no longer debug anything in firefox. At least with the iframe approach, the breakpoints work.

Can anyone shed some light into this problem?

Here is another related question that I asked yesterday which lead to finding this error: [Firefox Fail - After using document.write and update to location.hash causes page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908072/firefox-fail-after-using-document-write-and-update-to-location-hash-causes-pag)

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code

```
history.pushState(null,null,"#test")
```

before

```
document.open(); 
document.write(html); 
document.close();
```

Comment: The whole point is that the page that is written inside document.write is pushing the state. The bootstrap outer page is generating the HTML string and has no idea that the HTML it generated will need to push a new history state. The new HTML string contains a full web 2.0 type application that can do many different things. So adding `history.pushState` into the bootstrap page would make no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue trying to open an Ember app using history.pushState (Ember Router `location: 'history'` method of routing) inside an iframe.  It appears the issue only occurs when doing a hard refresh (`cmd + shift + r` on Mac or `ctrl + f5` on Windows) in Firefox. The issue only occurs for me in FireFox, works fine in Chrome and Safari with similar hard refresh.

The issue does not occur for me when navigating to the page for the first time or when normally refreshing the page (`cmd + r` Mac, `f5` Windows). I have found many seemingly related on Bugzilla for Mozilla but many are close. This one seems to represent the same issue I am having and is still open as of current versions of Firefox (v37.0.1 at time of writing).

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003100